# Python-code completion in studio-code just like swift's in xcode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-completion

Being used to the code completion for swift in xcode I ask myself if the code completion of python in visual-studio-code is really that bad or if i am really missing some important setting/configuration.

Using BeautifulSoup and having the following code

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html")
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")
print(bs.h1)
```

the h1 member was not found when pressing ctrl+space. This is really frustrating especially if you don't know all the methods/members off by heart and just want to look them up via ctrl+space.

Or do i really have to look up members/functions in the implementation each time?

I checked if the needed extensions are installed. I installed the extensions recommended by visual studio code such as the python extension by microsoft. When typing `from bs4 import` the code completion worked, `BeautifulSoup` was seen in a dropdown menue. So i assume visual studio is aware of the installed libraries.

I am thankful to any hint that helps me out!

Comment: I thnk you answered yourself: VS Code for python isn't that good. Better editors are PyCharm, and even the new version of Pyscripter, which both have an interactive REPL that VS Code doesn't have.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I use VS Code as my primary editor at work. VS Code definitely *does* have an interactive REPL.

Comment: you mean with completion and all? the one I saw was just a lame CMD console with python running on it

Comment: That's certainly not true: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_autocomplete-and-intellisense

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre VSCode lets you specify arbitrary terminals that it attaches to a pane on its UI, which could be a cmd console, could be your favorite terminal emulator, you could use its debug hooks to get an interactive console digging into the current runtime state of your program (stopped at the breakpoints you define)

Answer (score 0):

In principle **InteliSense** should work with Python.

What you might need to do is to [set your interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter) correctly. You can do that in the bottom left corner of the screen.
If you are working with virtual environments the interpreter should be set accordingly otherwise VS-Code does not know about **BeautifulSoup**.

Last but not least VS-Code also supports [linting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting).

Comment: In addition, something like `bs.h1` might only be known about at runtime. Intellisense won't know that `http://pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html` has an H1 tag until the HTML is parsed, which might be very expensive (if `pythonscraping.com` responds slowly or etc) so Intellisense will not attempt to do that just to give you better code completion.